# Cant open emulators directly from VS Code. No errors shown

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open my emulators from android studio to VS code for my flutter project. I install like 5-6 different emulators but vs code recognize them only when i open android studio and start them from there.

Also vs code has still my old emulator open by default but i have delete this one like a month ago.

Can anyone tell me what is going on  ?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: are u running flutter? Can u type `flutter doctor -v` in your vs code terminal?

Comment: Sure ... i get zero errors... but i have this problem on my react native  projects too.